# How can I share JAR file dependecies on a network between Eclipse users?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, ivy

I want to have a central JAR repository so all Eclipse users can import JAR dependencies from a central location no matter what operating system they are using.

I thought about Windows file sharing, but it gets complicated in Linux.

I thought Apache Ivy could help but I could not find out how to use it for my purpose.

If you are going to mention Maven, Ant, Ivy or any other Apache software, please show my a simple document where it explains how to use it as a repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like a file sharing method [FTP, etc], go for a source code sharing method [git, SVN, etc]
I may do with `git`, since it is cross platform, and can do many more things.....

Anyway it needs a local copy. But I think its good since otherwise compiling may waste lot of time.
Since eclipse has git plugins, it'll be an added advantage.
http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Comment: but i want to share JAR files not source code. you know how you import JAR files in Eclipse? that purpose.

Comment: it doesn't matter whether the file is a source code or a binary... if it supports your need. since it is a set of libraries, you may need previous versions someday. Doesn't you?

Comment: but how do I import them in build path? there are plugins for git to do that?

Comment: Your jar files should be inside a folder already included in the jar path. you can simply init your git folder. Other persons can add a remote reference to you. or the same can be done in a centralized location.
hope this link may help : http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/ also have a look in here
http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/

Answer (score 0):

Maven connects to a [*Nexus*](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install.html), which is the actual repository server you'd need to stand up and configure. You can start adding your collection of JARs and other artifacts, and can [configure Maven](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html) to be your build and dependency management tool for your teams' projects.

The Maven/Nexus combination is certainly agnostic to an OS. As long as you install maven (or, more typically, an IDE plugin), and have network connectivity, you're good to go.

Comment: see until now i though maven can also acts as a server. I hate Apaches documentation.

Comment: Lol, I see. Yeah, the Nexus is your repo. Now that you have that understanding, you should have be able to find mountains of tutorials on how to set things up. If your team is fairly savvy, you can do a lot of it in parallel, since Maven's basic build lifecycle is boilerplate. After you get a "sunny day" build workflow going you can start adding its ecosystem of plugins to tailor your particular needs.

Comment: Now maven does alot more, i just need to share my JAR files, does Ivy work the same way (i.e does it use nexus) or i have to go with maven?

Comment: You don't have to use Maven at all.  Nexus can be a standalone repository. You can provide permissions as to who can manage (e.g., add, delete) artifacts to the repository. Here's a [public Nexus](https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome) -- just try searching for an artifact like "BouncyCastle"

Comment: so how do i use it with Eclipse? is there a plugin like Ivy so it can add jar files from repository to my build path automatically?

Comment: For that I think you'll need the most vanilla implementation of maven, where you configure straightforward POM files in your projects that simply have the features for [dependency management](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_manage_dependencies.htm).

Comment: So just to confirm, Maven has 2 parts, one is the bin files, and the other is Eclipse plugin. If i'm correct, which one would I need to get?

Comment: I think you only need the m2e plugin for Eclipse, which I'm pretty sure comes out of the box with most versions. There's a simple "convert to Maven project" option in Eclipse's Project Explorer view which does exactly what it says. You then just need to point your [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file to point to your Nexus, and can then edit each project's POM (Eclipse even has a POM GUI so you don't have to directly work on raw XML) to choose which dependencies you want from that repository.

Comment: Overall it's quite painless to get a Nexus repo stood up and have your Maven projects pull from it.

Comment: And last question, can mu AR files stay in my local nexus and not get uploaded to the internet?

Comment: Absolutely. Your case is the default. You'd have to expose your server to the Internet to allow that.